# PersistGatae causes Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined error

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I am trying to figure put how to use Redux-Persist. I have the following code in my index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import storeConfig from "./app/config/store";

const AppRedux = () => (
  <Provider store={storeConfig.store}>
    <PersistGate presistor={storeConfig.persistor} loading={null}>
      <App />
     </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppRedux);
```

When I run it I get the following message:

> Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

BUT, When i comment out PersistGate I have no problems and my store gets rehydrated.

The reason I am trying to keep PersistGate is to have splash screen while rehydrating. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

P.S. This is what I have in store file:

```
export default () => {
  const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);
  const store = createStore(pReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(logger));
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};
```

Comment: Either it is the typo presistor or your storeConfig.persistor is undefined.

Comment: @Absor I tried logging persistor and I get empty object but it is not undefined.

Comment: And it wasn't the presistor typo? presistor={storeConfig.persistor} should be persistor={storeConfig.persistor}.

Comment: @Absor Thank you a lot! How could I miss that... :)